# Using the python sh module, how can I show the output of a command as it's happening?

Tags: python

The python `sh` module seem to wait until a command or at least a line is finished before it can show any of the output. How can I show the output of a command as it's happening?

Here's what I've tried so far. This is for git cloning something using `sh`.

```
for line in sh.git.clone(url, '--progress', '--recursive', _err_to_out=True, _iter=True):
    print(line)
```

And this prints every *line* after it's completed, but doesn't print it out in real time. So when I'm git cloning something, it doesn't show the progress of the clone, since it waits for the line to finish before it returns it. How can I have the `sh` module print out a command's progress in real time?

Comment: I just tried the above, and it seems to print things out in real time.  For example, https://asciinema.org/a/7l5z4phh3tw94mphvkqko9oex.  If you are seeing different behavior, give us more information about your environment (python version? operating system? etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `_out_bufsize` parameter.
In my case, works OK with 100...

```
for line in sh.git.clone(url, '--progress', '--recursive', _err_to_out=True, _iter=True, _out_bufsize=100):
    print(line)
```

**Output:**

> Cloning into 'some_project'...
>   remote: Counting objects: 70796, done. 
>   remote: Compressing objects:   0
>   remote: Compressing objects:   1% (203/20259)
>   remote: Compressing objects:   3% (608/20259)
>   remote: Compressing objects:   5% (1013/20259)
>   remote: Compressing objects:   7% (1419/20259)
>   remote: Compressing objects:   9% (1824/20259)